# Waiting for a program to load DLLs and then suspend it

Tags: windows, api, dll, load, hook

I want to hook an api as soon as a program loads. For that I use createprocess with the appropriate flag set so that the process is created suspended. I place the hook and then I resume it. But when I try to hook an api that's not from ntdll.DLL i get an ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS (487). If I wait until the program has started to place the hook, I can do it without trouble.

This leads me yo believe that the process doesn't load every DLL when it starts (even though they are linked statically), and there is some initialization to be done before the memory area on the iat that corresponds to the api I want to hook, is valid and ready to be accessed.

Am I right here? And if so, what can I do in order to know when to place the hook?

Thanks!

PD: I'm working on a proof of concept for my future thesis. It's purely for educational purposes.

PD2: I hooked the entry point and it worked great but now I have another conundrum: I need a standardized way of knowing the entry point of a loaded process.

Comment: You'd have to write a debugger so you can use the DLL load notification.  That is [easier than it sounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'd rather not use debugging. I don't want the process to know it's being debugged. Is there another way?

Comment: That's quite nonsensical.

Comment: How so? There are programs that might not run if they are being debugged. Quite a lot actually.

Comment: Not on my planet.  Programs that have anti-debugging techniques also have a license that's adamant about not messing with them.  Don't be evil.  Don't bug us with gaming cheats.

Comment: Not evil, not a gaming cheat. If you have to know I'm working on a proof of concept for my future thesis. But if you don't want to help me, I understand.

Comment: Pretty sure that comment was helpful.  If you have bizarre requirements that you never mention in your question then you'll never get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry first question here. Thanks for the feedback I'll modify my question.

Comment: Perhaps you could first hook the entry point for the process, and then hook the statically linked DLLs at that point?  The main catch would be that any DllMain functions will already have been run, and some may call back into the main application, e.g., C++ initializers for static objects.  You might be able to hook those callbacks too, I suppose, depending on how much information you have about the application in question.

Comment: Actually you read my mind, that's exactly what I did. But now I have another question, I updated it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmmm.  I believe there are additional undocumented options to GetThreadInformation, one of those might contain the start point.  Or perhaps you could attach to the process as a debugger, get the information you need, then detach using `DebugActiveProcessStop` before allowing the thread to actually start running?  Alternatively, the entry point could be retrieved from the executable file; the PE format is documented.  Of course any of these will give you the true entry point (the runtime library entry point) rather than the main() function or equivalent.

Comment: I'd rather not debug the process, this poc should be done in such a way that's compatible with as many executables as possible. This is the reason why I just don't hard code the entry point to 0x00400000. I believe that there is a complete image of the executable in the process memory. How can I get the starting position of it? Is it located at 0?

Comment: I'm not aware of any anti-debugging techniques that would work when the debugger has detached itself before the process even started.  But your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!!

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO sInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&sInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    CreateProcess("c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, nullptr, nullptr, &sInfo, &pInfo);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pInfo.dwProcessId);
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbaseInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&pbaseInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION));
    DWORD dwRet = 0;
    ZwQueryInformationProcess = (DWORD (__stdcall *)(HANDLE, PROCESSINFOCLASS, PVOID, ULONG, PULONG))GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"),"ZwQueryInformationProcess");
    ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, 0, &pbaseInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION), &dwRet);
    SIZE_T imageBase = 0;
    SIZE_T dwret1;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (BYTE*) pbaseInfo.PebBaseAddress + 8, &imageBase, 4, &dwret1);
    BYTE *buffer = new BYTE[sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32));
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*) imageBase, buffer, sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32), &dwRead);
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) buffer;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32) (buffer + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
    cout << (hex) << ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + imageBase << endl;
    TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

There might be some tweaks to do, but that's the basic jist of it.